# 'open' REST framework (.Net)

Tags: c#, rest

We have a homegrown framework that might be useful
to implement REST based webservices.

It is a .net c# project, used in a webapplication.

What it is used like: inline substitution of template 'tags' with dynamic content. sample tag: {{recentposts window=7 max=10}}

What it does: parsing 'tag' to command with (checked) parameters, invoking a 
handler configured to handle the command and return data, transforming the data with xsl,
substitute {{...}} with the result.

I have a hunch that this could be reworked to create some form of REST based
services, parsing an url to a command with parameters, invoking a handler etc.
and writing the result to http response.

As an alternative to reworking I'm looking for smth
that might be useable instead, out of the box.

What are mature (open source) frameworks that could be used?
It has to provide a http facade, to do the REST stuff easily, and besides provide an API, 
a way to bypass this facade, allowing command objects to be created, having all the invocation and transformation done and instead of writing to http response to some stream.

Comment: you don't write which C# version you use... have you looked at the built-in WCF REST classes ? MSDN reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx

Answer (score 3):

How about [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/)?

Quote from the webpage:

> A modern, code-first, DTO-driven, WCF replacement web services framework encouraging best-practices for creating DRY, high-perfomance, scalable REST web services

...and an ["overview" slideshow](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dg3mcfb_208gv3kcnd8).

Answer (score 1):

I use [EasyHttp](https://github.com/hhariri/EasyHttp) to work with REST base serices, it works easily with JSON and XML services and also supports working with retrieved object as a dynamic object. Very easy to plug and use and you don't have to worry about Http Request/Response anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be worth taking a look at OpenRasta

https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-stable/wiki

> The OpenRasta project is a web framework that les you build web
>   applications as simple as
>
> public class Home {   public string Get() {
>       return "Hello world";   } }

It's really nice to use and easy to get started with